# Regex to convert video from custom input into HTML

Tags: php, regex, filter, pcre

I'm currently trying to write a filter which will convert some simple input text
such as *Markdown* or plain text into some HTML. The idea is to give the ability to
the end user to add some videos into the content. So the input could contain simple
*Markdown* and then some tags, looking like this:

```
[video url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak" width=100% ratio='16/9'
autoplay:1 caption:"Lea Verou - Regexplained"]
```

I want to be rather soft in the syntax and allow `:` or `=` between the attribute
name and the value. And like in HTML, values can be optionally single or double quoted
to solve problems with spaces or special chars. And this is where I start to struggle!

For the moment, I wrote this regex in PHP:

```
/(?(DEFINE)
# This sub-routine will match an attribute value with or without the quotes around it.
# If the value isn't quoted then we can't accept spaces, quotes or the closing ] tag.
(?<attr_value_with_delim>(?:(?<delimiter>["']).*?(?:\k<delimiter>)|[^"'=\]\s]+))
)

\[
\s*video\s+
(?=[^\]]*\burl[=:](?<url>\g<attr_value_with_delim>))      # Mandatory URL
(?=[^\]]*\bwidth[=:](?<width>\g<attr_value_with_delim>))? # Optional width
(?=[^\]]*\bratio[=:](?<ratio>\g<attr_value_with_delim>))? # Optional ratio
(?=[^\]]*\bautoplay[=:](?<autoplay>\g<attr_value_with_delim>))? # Optional autoplay
(?=[^\]]*\bcaption[=:](?<title>\g<attr_value_with_delim>))? # Optional caption
[^\]]*
\]/guxs
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/hVsav8/1

The optional attribute values are captured so that I don't need to
reparse the matched tags a second time.

My questions:

- How can I handle the problem of a `]` inside the value of an attribute?
- Would it be possible to capture the value without the quotes?

  It's not very important as I can get rid of it later with `trim(..., '"\'')`
  in the callback but I would be interested to see if there's a pattern solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subroutines:

```
(?(DEFINE)

# Match quote-delimited values

  (?<attr_value_with_delim>
    '(?:\\.|[^'])*'
  |
    "(?:\\.|[^"])*"
  )

# Match non-quote-delimited values

  (?<attr_value_without_delim>[^'"\s[\]]+)

# Match both types

  (?<attr_value>
    \g<attr_value_with_delim>
  |
    \g<attr_value_without_delim>
  )

# Match attr - value pairs in the following forms:
## attr:value
## attr=value
## attr:"value'[]=:"
## attr='value"[]=:'
## attr:"val\"ue"
## attr:'val\'ue'

  (?<attr_with_value>
    \s+[a-zA-Z]+[:=]\g<attr_value>
  )
)
```

Actual matching pattern:

```
\[\s*                             # Opening bracket followed by optional whitespaces
video                             # Literal 'video'
\g<attr_with_value>*              # 0+ attribute - value pairs
(?:                               #
  \s+                             # Preceding whitespaces
  url[:=]                         # Literal 'url' followed by either ':' or '='
  (?:                             # 
    '\s*(?:\\.|[^'\s])+\s*'       # Single or double quote-delimited,
  |                               # space-surrounded (optional)
    "\s*(?:\\.|[^"\s])+\s*"       # URL that doesn't contain whitespaces
  |                               #
    \g<attr_value_without_delim>  # or a non-quote-delimited value
  )                               #
)                                 #
\g<attr_with_value>*              # 0+ attribute - value pairs
\s*\]                             # Optional whitespaces followed by closing bracket
```

This regex matches a video notation which can then be further parsed using legitimate and non-devilish ways. It proves but parsing HTML-like content with regex is strongly discouraged.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hVsav8/3).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this nice and complete solution with multiple subroutines! I'm sorry, I didn't explicitly say that I would like to capture the attribute values within capturing groups, so that I don't need to reparse the found tags a second time.

Comment: That would be multiple times harder, unfortunately...